# JSON: How do I prepend parameter name to each of its values?

Tags: javascript, json, reporting-services

I use the following code to return a JSON string and convert it to a URL.

```
function runMyReport(){ 
        var json = ko.toJSON(getParams());
        var url = "/Report/rvp.aspx?id=" + guestId() + "&" + $.param({ "parameters": json });
}
```

The problem is that if any parameter has multiple values then it will render as:

{"Product" : "1,2,3"}

and need it to prepend the parameter name to each value and return as:

{"Product" : "1", "Product" : "2", "Product" : "3"}

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this?

The reason I need to do this is I created a drop-down field using the below JS array of objects.

```
var product= [
        { name: "All", id: "1, 2, 3" },
        { name: "key1", id: "1" },
        { name: "key2", id: "2" },
        { name: "key3", id: "3" }
```

The object "All" has multiple values and when selected displays in the JSON as "Product" : "1,2,3". The problem is that SSRS only accepts multiple values in the following query string format:

```
querystring.aspx?product=1&product=2&product=3
```

Comment: Why would you want an object representation that reuses the same key? How are you going to access its value?

Comment: Just added the reason to the original post. Thank you for responding as well.

Comment: So you're really asking how to convert it to `product=1&product=2&product=3`, because I don't see how `{"Product" : "1", "Product" : "2", "Product" : "3"}` would relate to what you need.

Comment: Correct. Thank you very much for clarifying. I guess a better question would be how do I take the json data and convert it to a query string in that specific format?

Comment: Give this a shot: `$.param("1,2,3".split(",").map(function(n) { return {name: "Product", value: n} }))`. Here I used a string literal of `"1,2,3"`, but you'll instead use the value you're getting.

Comment: Got it! Thanks bud.